# Why package not installed when using subprocess.run to Install Microsoft Installer package (.msi)

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to install Microsoft Installer package (.msi) file using the following code
I'm not getting any error 
got the massage "Process finished with exit code 0"
I verified path is correct.
but the package is not installed 
what is wrong?

```
import subprocess

agent_arg = ('msiexec', '/i', r'C:\Users\shlomil\Desktop\Utilities_Installers_new\Programs\DataAgent.msi', '/qn')
subprocess.run(agent_arg)
```

Comment: are you running as admin?